# Interfacing of Nihon Kohden MEK6420P with PC

Tags: c

I have interfaced a Hematology Analyzer machine MEK6420P by Nihon Kohden with my PC through RS232C. I have written a C code for receiving data from MEK6420P into my PC. But I am receiving garbage data (actually data which can't be read by human) upon pressing send key on MEK6420P machine. I am also getting the data without sending acknowledgement signal to MEK6420P (which is opposed to communication protocol of MEK6420P). What can be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the relevent part of your code?

Comment: The crystal ball says there is some error in the code. Or the hardware. Or ...

Comment: MEK6420P uses ASTM 1381-02 protocol standard. So according to that standard following is part of my code.@mikeyq6

Comment: while(1) 
    {
        s=RS232_PollComport(port,buf,4096);
        if(s>0)
        {
            *(buf+s)=0;
            printf("Received %i bytes\n",s);
            printf("%s\n",(char *)buf);
        }
    }                                                                                                            I am using rs232.h library for serial communication @mikeyq6

Comment: When I run this program I get response from MEK6420P like this:      eui¥“—ŸŸ¿¿å¿¿¿åŸŸ›—åe}cU}g¿¿¿¿¿¿åy{y¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿åŸå{gaaw¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿åeee¿åŸŸ™

Comment: What are you talking about? I mean who says there can be a problem in code?@Olaf